# element not clickable for chrome driver protractor angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, protractor

I am trying to click the second level menu options which will expand to third level. some of the menu options not getting clicked. I added  browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1280, 1024 ) in before all section.

below is my code:

```
it('Should expect clicking the second level menu option  will expand the third level', () => {
  element.all((by.css('div.panel.panel-default'))).click().then(() => {
    var groupList = element.all((by.css('.list-group-header.sub-menu-header.active-element')));
    // expect(groupList.get(1).getAttribute('class')).toMatch('active-element');
    expect(groupList.count()).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: I want to click each element by  "by.css('div.panel.panel-default')" this selector one by one...If some one can help me with how to use each function with element all  and how can I click each element here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we are dealing with multi-level menus, it's good to use  protractor.ExpectedConditions for checking element's visibility and clickable status.

And in your case, use '***each()***' method of protractor for clicking each element.Hope below code will help you.

```
Code Snippet:

var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var timeout=5000;

it('Should expect clicking the second level menu option  will expand the 
   third level', () => {
   element.all((by.css('div.panel.panel-default'))).each(function(ele,index) 
    {
     //check whether each element becomes visibile or not
     browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(ele), timeout).thenCatch(function () {
     assert.fail('element is not visibile');
                  });
     //check whether each element is clickable or not
     browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(ele), timeout).thenCatch(function   
     () {
        assert.fail('element is not click able');
          });
     //then click each element
     ele.click().then(function(){
     var groupList = element.all((by.css('.list-group-header.sub-menu-
                                 header.active-element')));
     // expect(groupList.get(1).getAttribute('class')).toMatch('active- 
        element');
     expect(groupList.count()).toEqual(1);
    });   
   });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Suresh

Comment: Yes, i used a different  way to solve it, however, this is really helpful and i will have to use it in future. Thanks once again:)

Comment: if my solution works for you, tick it as correct. @user3444776